# Where is documentation about EXTRA_SCRIPTS variable in autotools?

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

What is EXTRA_SCRIPTS variable for in Makefile.am? Where is it documented?

Comment: This is project specific - what is it for? Is it for GNU PrivacyGuard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Uniform.html):

> For each primary, there is one additional variable named by prepending ‘EXTRA_’ to the primary name. This variable is used to list objects that may or may not be built, depending on what configure decides. This variable is required because Automake must statically know the entire list of objects that may be built in order to generate a Makefile.in that will work in all cases.

The `SCRIPTS` primary is described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Scripts.html).

In short, the `EXTRA_SCRIPTS` variable lists scripts (that is, executable files that do not need to be built from source) that may or may not be used, depending on the configuration.

Comment: Close, but not quite. Scripts can still be built (using something like `sed` to make substitutions from a template, say), they just don't have a link step involving a true linker like `ld`. `EXTRA_SCRIPTS` is then scripts that may or may not be built, depending on the configuration.